# What's the status on Serum cranking?

Tags: serum, serum-market

we're developing our own custom serum market with our token. We've established a serum market ('FvhTW3kMofdmfvC6H2bJLuYysikBkLoS8PVLMFtuYjqW') but was having some troubles with openOrders balance not being updated after a fill. No one is using this market except for the developers at the moment.

Turns out this was a cranking issue and as soon as I did a manual crank on the market my openOrders account was showing the correct balance. Can someone give me a rundown on how serum market's are cranked. Our market is not getting cranked automatically.

The docs state that: "A node is a collection of SRM staking together, including at least one MSRM. Nodes manage much of the Serum ecosystem. Since nodes handle cranking, users interested in adding their own markets only have to bring their own liquidity"

This does not seem to be the case for our market. And we've setup a cranking bot for ourselves. Can we add this to a list of markets crank by the cranking nodes somehow?

Answer (score 1):

so as you saw yourself, on cranking (or consuming events), the open orders updated to the correct balance and that is the desired behaviour.

When orders are places in a market, certain events, either `Fill` or `Out` are pushed into the Event Queue. A `Fill` event signifies an order being filled whereas an `Out` event signify an order being removed from the Orderbook.

Now, these events need to be consumed (or cranked) for the state of your OpenOrder to be updated. Cranking is the process where one sends a `ConsumeEvents` instruction in regular intervals to keep the EventQueue empty. In `mainnet` markets, this is done by many organizations out there who run some sort of process in a server which does this.

And to answer your question about adding it to the existing list of markets being cranked, I believe that's something that's upto the organizations running the cranks. If you would like to start out your market on `mainnet`, I believe you would have to start out with your own crank initially.

On the other hand, for local development, you could use [`serum-dev-tools`](https://www.wordcelclub.com/sayantan.sol/getting-started-with-serum-dex) and [`Serum Explorer`](https://serum-explorer.vercel.app/) to test out functionality.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that the market you mentioned has USDC has its Base Token and ISKT as its Quote Token. Is that how it's supposed to be? Usually USDC is kept as the Quote Token.

https://serum-explorer.vercel.app/market/FvhTW3kMofdmfvC6H2bJLuYysikBkLoS8PVLMFtuYjqW